# Find a distribution and probability.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification

Consider a box with $n$ black and $m$ white balls, we randomly pick some $k$ of them(balls picked one by one), but if we pick white ball we get it back to box. Now we want to build a distribution for this task and find probability that we pick exactly $r$ black balls.

**EDIT**

My attempt : 
Suppose we pick some $i$ white balls , then there is $\binom{m+i-1}{i}$ (that's number of ways to pick it without order with returning) ways to pick it. Now there are $\binom{n}{k-i}$ (because we should choose $k-i$ balls from $n$ black balls) ways to pick black ball , so there are $\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{m+i-1}{i} \binom{n}{k-i}$ (all possible ways to pick them) ways to pick $k$ balls from box. Now the probability of choosing exactly $r$ black balls is : 
$\displaystyle \frac{\binom{n}{r}\binom{m+k-r-1}{k-r}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{m+i-1}{i}\binom{n}{k-i}}$

I've edited some wrong assumption.

First of all : am I right ? If yes , does there some chances to simplify the sum ?

Comment: If you pick up the balls only once what is the sense in getting white balls back to box? May it be that you are interested in getting exactly $r$ black balls after say $N$ steps?

Comment: @user I pick up some $k$ balls. It make sense to return white balls.

Comment: May it be that you pick up the balls *one by one* and in the case if it is a white ball you put it back in the box, and $k$ is not the number of balls but the number of trials?

Comment: "Suppose we pick some $i$ white balls , then there is $A^i_m=m!/(m−i)!$ (because balls are get back to box) ways to pick it." This statement is wrong. There are $m^i$ such ways. Consider for example the case that all $i$ times the same white ball was picked up.

Comment: @user no , suppose we have three balls and we select two of them. Let $\{1,2,3\}$ be balls then we can make a pairs (1,2), (1,3) , (1,1) , (2,2) ,(2,3) and (3,3) , and that's equal to $3! /(3-2)! = 6$

Comment: The order plays role. Add pairs (2,1),(3,1),(3,2) and you obtain $9=3^2$.

Comment: @user why should it play a role. Even in hypergeometrical distribution (if we don't return balls) order doesn't play a role

Comment: If you count all possible results you should assume that the balls are numbered and record both color and number as you pick them up.

Comment: Yes , but we talk about only white balls. And consider a part of choosing $i$ balls from $m$ white balls. And my question is why should it be ordered? 
If we consider just a hypergeometrical distribution order doesn't play a role and the answer for choosing $i$ balls from $m$ is $\frac{m!}{i!(m-i)!}$. Now we have property, that we can return balls. So number. of white balls is constant. So we can select them with $\frac{m!}{(m-i)!}$ different ways (without respect of order). But why should it be ordered?

Comment: Try to perform numerical tests and report on the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that all balls are numbered and record the  number and the color of the picked ball in each trial. Assume altogether $r$ black balls were picked up after $k$ trials. There are $\binom{n}{r}$ ways to choose the balls and $\binom{k}{r}$ ways to choose the trials which have given the balls. Besides the balls can be permuted between the chosen trials in $r!$ ways.
The rest $k-r$ trials give white balls and this can happen in $m^{k-r}$ ways. Thus the overall number of $k$ trials resulting in $n$ black balls is
$$
N(k,r)=r!\binom{n}{r}\binom{k}{r}m^{k-r},
$$ 
and the corresponding probability:
$$
P(k,r)=\frac{N(k,r)}{\sum_{r=0}^kN(k,r)}.
$$

Comment: What is $l_{i}$?

Comment: And what is the problem in my answer?

Comment: @openspace I have added an explanation for the meaning of indices $l_i$. What concerns your answer I am not quite sure what do you mean with $A^i_m$. Have you already checked both versions?

Comment: $A_{m}^{i} = \frac{m!}{(m-i)!}$

Comment: Please add in your question the idea behind using the value. I do not see how the possibility to draw the same white ball again is accounted for.

Comment: that's right my bad

Comment: Why should it be $\sum_{i} l_{i} $?
I understand that first multiplier for $r$ black balls and the second one for all possible arrangements of $k-r$ white balls.

Comment: We should consider all possible ways to arrange $k-r$ white balls in the sequence of $k$ balls, compute the probability for this particular arrangement and then add. This is correct. However I have now doubts that the full analogy with choosing with replacement really works. I will edit my answer and propose another approach which gives very similar but still different result.

Comment: Your answer is correct!
I understand it using probability tree. In term of tree : we should summarize probabilities according to trees with exactly $r$ black sons. But it also the same as have at the end $n-r$ do not using black balls.

Comment: Your addition is very close to numerical. Actually the bottom one is correct. I will try to understand it. Thanks a lot